# Ext.Net how to get all TreeNode IN TreePanel AS List<Node>

Tags: extjs, ext.net

Ext.Net how to get all TreeNode IN TreePanel AS List

```
foreach(Node treenode in treepanel.Nodes) {
   string nodeID = treenode.NodeID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Recursively:

```
    //Create a list 
    List<Node> list = new List<Node>();

    //pass you tree root as a parameter
    GetAllNodes(YourTreePanel.root);


    protected void GetAllNodes(NodeCollection nodes) {

        foreach (Node item in nodes)
        {  
            //if your node has children call the function again                
            if (item.Children.Count > 0) GetAllNodes(item.Children);

            //finally add the node to the list 
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
```